# WebPart Error after Upgrade to SP1 & June Cumulative update

Tags: 2010, web-part

I am getting following error after I did an update to SP1

> Web Part Error: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform
>   this action or access this resource.

The above error crops up when the user accessing the page has Limited Access permission level. However, pre-SP1 the webparts where hidden if the user had Limited Access.

Comment: Hello, If the webpart is custom coded then you will get the error. So open the webpart and redeploy to your site. Hope the information helps

Comment: Thx. Webparts are not custom coded.

Comment: What does your web part do, exactly?

Comment: Webparts show the above given error message instead of staying hidden when a person with limited access logs in.

Comment: I believe James was asking what the purpose of the web part is, what functions does it provide and what resources does it consume?